# How to access the children of a dynamically added child in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to access "results" because it has a solid name which never changes. But the children under "results" are dynamically added. How am I able to iterate through the children of "results" and then access "datum"?

*For each child under "results" I want to make a cardview which will be set in a recyclerviewer with the "datum" in a TextView and the (Base64)Strings in a Imageview.*

[image]

**EDIT**
I tried this:

```
resultsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("results"); 

resultsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String datumStr = ds.child("datum").getValue(String.class);
                            holder.datum.setText(datumStr);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: So you want to get the values of "datum" for each and every child within the "results" node?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes that is what I want. I made an edit with what I tried. Still not working like that, but am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a reference to `getReference("users").child("results");` in the database. But there is no `/users/results`, so the `snapshot` you get will be empty.

So you'll need to laod the entire `users` node, and then get `results` from each child:

```
resultsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("results"); 

resultsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot resultsSnapshot: userSnapshot.getChild("results");
            for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: resultsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String datumStr = ds.child("datum").getValue(String.class);
                holder.datum.setText(datumStr);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Note how giving the snapshots meaningful names above helps in understand what they actually refer to.

---

Also: you're nesting different types of data (user profiles, and their results) under a single top-level node, which the Firebase documentation explicitly recommends against in its [best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).

One disadvantage of your current approach is that in order to for example show a list of user names, you'll end up loading all results for all those users too. Even if that is not a security concern for your app, it's most certainly a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: It kinda works now, but it's only getting the very last child of results. How should I pass it from the login activity to another fragment? Right now I'm using sharedPref, but I don't think it's the right way. Should I use Bundle instead?

Comment: "it's only getting the very last child of results" More likely it is getting all results, but only show the last one in the holder because `holder.datum.setText(datumStr)` overwrites all previous results. You'll have to figure out for yourself how you want to show the multiple results; my answer is merely meant to point out why you're not getting data from Firebase with your existing code, and one way to fix that.

Comment: Passing them in a bundle and/or sharedPrefs can both be fine. Or you can reload them in the next activity too. Whatever works for you.

Comment: It is also duplicating that last item in the recyclerview. Thanks for your help so far by the way. It solved my first initial problem!